# LL(1) Parse table for S → a | ba | c

Tags: parsing, context-free-grammar, ll-grammar, context-free-language

I'm new to LL(1) parsing and am currently trying to figure out how to create a parse table for the language:

```
 S → Saa|b
```

and

```
 S-> A|B
 A-> aa
 B-> bb
```

and

```
 S → AB
 A → aa
 B → bb
```

Comment: Which type of parse table do you want to build? LL, SLR, LR(1)? Where are you stuck? If you don't know where to start maybe it is better to buy a book.

Comment: An LL(1) parse table

Answer (score 3):

I'll show you the complete procedure for the first grammar. Tell me if there are any aspects you would like to examine in greater depth.

S → Saa | b

### **1. Eliminate left recursion**

S →  bS'

S' → aaS' | ε

### **2. Left factor**

No need for this grammar.

### **3. Compute FIRST and FOLLOW and check if the grammar is LL(1)**

```
------------------------------------
|   A → α   | FIRST(α) | FOLLOW(A) |
------------------------------------
|  S → bS'  |     a    |      $    |
------------------------------------
| S' → aaS' |     a    |      $    |
------------------------------------
|   S' → ε  |     ε    |      $    |
------------------------------------
```

### **4. Build the parsing table**

```
for each prodution A → α
  for each a ∈  FIRST(α)
    add production A → α to M[A,a]
  if ε ∈ FIRST(α) then
    for each b ∈ FOLLOW(A)
      add A → α to M[A,b]
```

Result:

```
-------------------------------------
|    |    a     |    b     |   $    |
-------------------------------------
| S  |          |  S → bS' |        |
-------------------------------------
| S' | S → aaS' |          | S' → ε |
-------------------------------------
```

The grammar is LL(1). Here the results of the other grammars.

```
1.
-------------------------------------
|    |    a     |    b     |   $    |
-------------------------------------
| S  |   S → A  |  S → B   |        |
-------------------------------------
| A  |  A → aa  |          |        |
-------------------------------------
| B  |          |  B → bb  |        |
------------------------------------- 

2.
-------------------------------------
|    |    a     |    b     |   $    |
-------------------------------------
| S  |   S → AB |          |        |
-------------------------------------
| A  |  A → aa   |         |        |
-------------------------------------
| B  |          |  B → bb  |        |
-------------------------------------
```